# ListView - Load more items with scroll

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-scrollview

I need help with listview I am using in a fragment. The app reads data from an API and my code works fine. I load 15 items initially and every next time I load 10 items more. However if a request to the API return less than 15 items, it doesn't work. Also, the app fails when the number of items is not a multiple of 15 or 25 or 35. That is because I load 10 items after the initial setup.

I need to modify my code for it to work with any number of list items.

My code is as follows:

(ListaFragment.java) -> Here is the ListFragment

```
    public class ListaFragment extends ListFragment implements OnScrollListener {
    public ListaFragment(){}
    View rootView;

    ListAdapter customAdapter = null;
    ListaLugares listaLugares;    

    // values to pagination
    private View mFooterView;
    private final int AUTOLOAD_THRESHOLD = 4;
    private int MAXIMUM_ITEMS;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private boolean mIsLoading = false;
    private boolean mMoreDataAvailable = true;
    private boolean mWasLoading = false;

    public int ventana = 0;
    public int nInitial;

    private Runnable mAddItemsRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter.addMoreItems(10);
            mIsLoading = false;

        }
    };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container, false);

        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setBar();


        // read number of places of a category
        listaLugares.readNumberOfPlaces();
        // set
        setNumbersOfItems();
        // read the places a insert in a List
        listaLugares.readPlaces(15, ventana, listaLugares.idCategoria);
        //ventana = ventana + 25;

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listaLugares = ((ListaLugares)getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = getActivity();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        customAdapter = new ListAdapter(context, listaLugares.lista);

        mFooterView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.loading_view, null);
        getListView().addFooterView(mFooterView, null, false);
        setListAdapter(customAdapter);
        getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
    }


    public void setNumbersOfItems() {
        if (listaLugares.totalItems > 100) {
            MAXIMUM_ITEMS = 100;
            nInitial = 25;
        } else {
            MAXIMUM_ITEMS = listaLugares.totalItems;
            nInitial = listaLugares.totalItems;
        }
        Log.v("NUMBER OF ITEMS", "Number: " + MAXIMUM_ITEMS + "-"+ nInitial);
    }



    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetalleActivity.class);
        //myIntent.putExtra("param_id", appState.lista.get(position).id);
        //getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

         if (!mIsLoading && mMoreDataAvailable) {
             if (totalItemCount >= MAXIMUM_ITEMS) {
                 mMoreDataAvailable = false;
                 getListView().removeFooterView(mFooterView);
             } else if (totalItemCount - AUTOLOAD_THRESHOLD <= firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) {
                 ventana = ventana + 10;
                 listaLugares.readPlaces(10, ventana, listaLugares.idCategoria);
                 mIsLoading = true;
                     mHandler.postDelayed(mAddItemsRunnable, 1000);
             }
         }
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Ignore
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mWasLoading) {
            mWasLoading = false;
            mIsLoading = true;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mAddItemsRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAddItemsRunnable);
        mWasLoading = mIsLoading;
        mIsLoading = false;
        ventana = ventana;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

(ListAdapter.java) -> Method in adapter class to add more items.

```
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lugar> {
Context context;
List<Lugar> values;

ListaLugares listaLugares;

private int mCount = 20;


public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Lugar> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    TextView firstText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
    TextView secondText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.categoria);

    firstText.setText(values.get(position).nombre);
    secondText.setText(values.get(position).categoriaNombre);

    return row;
}


public void addMoreItems(int count) {
    mCount += count;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

}
```

Comment: Please only include `related code` into the question, see http://sscce.org/

Comment: i use this one http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/

Comment: Ok, I've edit the code in ListAdapter but I can not summarize ListaFragment because all code is important. Thanks for the suggestion ;)

Comment: you can check the ApiDemos, there's a nice example that do that.

Answer (score 1):

I acceded to a previous edited version to see some code.

The first call works because you are starting with a value of 15 on `initiaItems` and you set it on `mCount` on the `ListAdapter` constructor.

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Lugar> values, int count) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.mCount = count;
}
```

So when android renders the listview, it acces to the function `ListAdapter.getCount()` and returns `mCount` (15).

But when you scroll it can call to

```
public void addMoreItems(int count, int idCategoria) {
    appState = ((ListaLugares)getContext().getApplicationContext());
    appState.readPlaces(15, mCount, idCategoria);
    mCount += count;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If the number of items returned by the  `appState.readPlaces` is unknown why are you adding a number to mCount `mCount += count;`?

If `appState.readPlaces` returns 14 and `count` is 15 when the listview is rendered it will suppose there are 15+15 items when there are 15+14 so the last item will crash.

`mCount` should obtain the length from the object that keeps the data from the API calls, in your case I think it will be `appState.lista`.

Comment: I modified my code but I cant solve my problem. My new code is in question. I follow the next tutorial: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2066699&seqNum=4

Comment: If we have the values list how about `return (mCount > values.size()) ? values.size() : mCount` instead of `return mCount`